# No schemata were loaded

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I'm trying to generate code from db schema using jooq ([tutorial](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/getting-started/tutorials/jooq-in-7-steps/jooq-in-7-steps-step3/)). I'm getting the following warning:

```
WARNING: No schemata were loaded  : Please check your connection settings, and whether your database (and your database version!) is really supported by jOOQ. Also, check the case-sensitivity in your configured <inputSchema/> elements : {=[library]}No schemata were loaded
```

That is my configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.11.0.xsd">
    <!-- Configure the database connection here -->
    <jdbc>
        <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
        <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/library</url>
        <user>jb</user>
    </jdbc>

    <generator>
        <!-- The default code generator. You can override this one, to generate your own code style.
             Supported generators:
             - org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator
             - org.jooq.codegen.ScalaGenerator
             Defaults to org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator -->
        <name>org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator</name>

        <database>
            <!-- The database type. The format here is:
                 org.jooq.meta.[database].[database]Database -->
            <name>org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>

            <!-- The database schema (or in the absence of schema support, in your RDBMS this
                 can be the owner, user, database name) to be generated -->
            <inputSchema>library</inputSchema>

            <!-- All elements that are generated from your schema
                 (A Java regular expression. Use the pipe to separate several expressions)
                 Watch out for case-sensitivity. Depending on your database, this might be important! -->
            <includes>.*</includes>

            <!-- All elements that are excluded from your schema
                 (A Java regular expression. Use the pipe to separate several expressions).
                 Excludes match before includes, i.e. excludes have a higher priority -->
            <excludes/>
        </database>

        <target>
            <!-- The destination package of your generated classes (within the destination directory) -->
            <packageName>jb</packageName>

            <!-- The destination directory of your generated classes. Using Maven directory layout here -->
            <directory>/home/jb/Workspace/JVM/jooq-demo/src/main/java</directory>
        </target>
    </generator>
</configuration>
```

This file was not modified in any way (the user `jb` has access to database without password, maybe that's the problem, although I couldn't find any info).

Also connection through intellij using the same config was succesful - I can see the `library` database and `author` table.

Comment: In PostgreSQL, "database" and "schema" are not the same thing. Are your tables really located in a schema called `library`?

Comment: Right, that was the problem. Stupid mistake. I actually managed to find it out, but did not close the question yet. Thank you though!